# Formatting Oracle query output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running following query against a schema in Oracle database to fetch some details....

```
SELECT USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT, TASKNAME 
  FROM USERDB t1 
  JOIN USERDB_TASKS t3 ON t1.USERID=t3.USERID 
  JOIN TASKS t2 ON t3.TASKSID=t2.TASKSID;
```

Here table USERDB contains column names USERID, USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT. Table USERDB_TASKS contains column names USERID, TASKSID. Table TASKS contains column names TASKSID, TASKNAME. For a particular user, USERID will be same in all tables. Similarly TASKSID for a particular task will be same in all tables.

I am getting output in below format:

```
USERNAME FULLNAME     DEPARTMENT TASKNAME
duryo    dur yogeli   IT         Domain admin
duryo    dur yogeli   IT         Session user
rected   rec tedenson SALES      Process manager
rected   rec tedenson SALES      DBA user
rected   rec tedenson SALES      Flow coordinator 
................................................
```

I mean for the same user there are multiple tasknames coming in last column.

The output format I want to create is like below...

```
USERNAME FULLNAME     DEPARTMENT TASKNAME
duryo    dur yogeli   IT         Domain admin, Session user
rected   rec tedenson SALES      Process manager, DBA user, Flow coordinator
```

Although I have a batch script which does this formatting for me after generating the output in a file, but I want to generate the formatted output using oracle query itself, if possible.

Any clue would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT
    USERNAME,
    FULLNAME,
    DEPARTMENT,
    LISTAGG(TASKNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASKNAME) TASKNAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    USERNAME,
    FULLNAME,
    DEPARTMENT;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @Tim..its working fine but the TASKNAME column values are coming in scattered letters, i.e. `P r o c e s s m a n a g e r, D B A u s e r, F l o w c o o r d i n a t o r`.

Comment: @Aarie This sounds like a presentation problem, not really an issue with my query.  Check your encoding for starters.

Comment: @Tim..I have simply put it like this `WITH MyTable AS (
SELECT USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT, TASKNAME FROM USERDB t1 JOIN USERDB_TASKS t3 ON t1.USERID=t3.USERID JOIN TASKS t2 ON t3.TASKSID=t2.TASKSID)`. Not sure from where its picking a trigger for this scattering and that too only in last column.

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem to me actually.  Or maybe some issue with your configuration of Oracle SQL developer.  My code works in the demo without this problem.

Comment: It looks like something else, because its coming like this even using script connecting to database and spooling the output. Anyway Thanks for your help ! :-)

Comment: @Tim..Problem identified...It would be so helpful if could have a look at this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369196/listagg-weird-concatenation] Thanks in advance !