# LISTAGG weird concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use below query to fetch required details...

```
SELECT
    USERNAME,
    FULLNAME,
    DEPARTMENT,
    LISTAGG(TASKNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASKNAME) TASKNAME
FROM USERDB t1 LEFT JOIN
USERDB_TASKS t3 ON t1.USERID=t3.USERID LEFT JOIN
TASKS t2 ON t3.TASKSID=t2.TASKSID
GROUP BY
    USERNAME,
    FULLNAME,
    DEPARTMENT;
```

`TASKNAME` column is populating values in weird format (in both SQL Developer as well as through a batch script) i.e. all characters of each word are scattered as given below, while in the actual table `TASKS`, Taskname values/words are normal.

```
USERNAME  FULLNAME      DEPARTMENT TASKNAME
duryo     dur yogeli    IT         D o m a i n a d m i n, S e s s i o n u s e r
rected    rec tedenson  SALES      P r o c e s s m a n a g e r, D B A u s e r, F l o . . .
```

Although I have used required formatting options given below in my script, I am not getting why such weird concatenation of values is happening by `LISTAGG` and how to fix this. I have counted that sum of all characters for all the tasknames available in table `TASKS` is just 130.

```
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET UNDERLINE off
set pagesize 0 embedded on
set linesize 100
column USERNAME format a15
column FULLNAME format a25
column DEPARTMENT format a15
column TASKNAME format a200
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT-1:** DUMP of the actual `TASKS` table values have weird character after each letter.

The output of the query:

`select taskname, dump(taskname, 17) as dump_test from TASKS` is having all weird characters like below..

`Process manager    Typ=1 Len=28: ^@,P,^@,r,^@,o,^@,c,^@,e,^@,s,^@,s,^@, ,^@,M,^@,a,^@,n,^@,a,^@,g,^@,e,^@,r`.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: That is weird. Are you familiar with the `dump` function? It can show you exactly what characters are stored (or generated by a query). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635 You could use it with the return_fmt = 17. Check values in the `TASKNAME` column as well as what `LISTAGG` returns.

Comment: @mathguy..I know the simple use of `DUMP`, but here I not getting how I can dump `TASKNAME` column and `LISTAGG` for the above complete query. Can you please let me know?

Comment: First, in your table: `select taskname, dump(taskname, 17) as dump_taskname from userdb;` and inspect the dumped values. It may show some funny characters after each letter - or not. For `LISTAGG`, similarly, add to your `SELECT` list the following expression: `dump(listagg(.....), 17) as dump_listagg` - then run the query and see if you notice anything funny in the dump.

Comment: @mathguy...You are right ! The output of the `select taskname, dump(taskname, 17) as dump_test from TASKS`  is having all weird characters like below..
`Process manager Typ=1 Len=28: ^@,P,^@,r,^@,o,^@,c,^@,e,^@,s,^@,s,^@, ,^@,M,^@,a,^@,n,^@,a,^@,g,^@,e,^@,r`  Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @mathguy This question is a follow up to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311286/formatting-oracle-query-output/54311341?noredirect=1#comment95555139_54311341).  I suggested that there might be an encoding problem here.  Could that be the case?

Comment: Interesting - I guess `^@` stands for the `NUL` character, `chr(0)`. You can find out for sure by running `dump(taskname)` (without the 17) - this will just show hexadecimal character codes, you should see `0` where you saw `^@` (or if it is not zero, please report back with what you see). In any case, to solve the problem there are two parts. One is trivial: `replace(taskname, chr(0))` will get rid of the unwanted characters. The other is to figure out why this is happening in the first place - and that has almost surely **nothing** to do with Oracle.

Comment: @mathguy...yes, confirmed its `0` only. Looks like this weird behavior is part of application setup. Anyway thank you so much for your help! I have added `replace(taskname, chr(0))` in `LISTAGG` and its working fine now. :-)

Comment: Is the `taskname` column defined as `nvarchar2`? It sounds like [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080115/266304) - does casting the column before aggregrating help in your case too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add some documentation on the DUMP function for others that come across this question.

Your issue is interesting.  From what all of you have figured out it appears that the column is fine as the dump function is simply showing that the field is a Varchar2 field shown by the output of the dump function - Typ=1.  I've pasted below an image of some of the Dump Data Type values I have been able to document.

[image]

I've pasted below a nice code snippet to provide examples of working with Oracle's Dump function.

```
SELECT 
    DUMP(to_date('15-JAN-18'),10,1,1) AS date_type
  , DUMP(123,10,1,1)   AS num_type
  , DUMP('abc',10,1,1) AS var_or_char_type
FROM dual
;

/* OUTPUT: 
 |
 | "DATE_TYPE"          "NUM_TYPE"          "VAR_OR_CHAR_TYPE"
 |--------------------|-------------------|------------------
 | "Typ=13 Len=8: 226"  "Typ=2 Len=3: 194"  "Typ=96 Len=3: 97"
*/
```

Basically, locate the entity that is populating this data in this field  and fix it at it's source if you want to rid yourself of these strange characters.